# Chatter feed says Chatter isn't enabled or the user doesn't have Chatter access

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed, chatter-feed-tracking

Hi I have to enable chatter to post comments for knowledge articles. So I enabled chatter, enable feed tracking for knowledge object. We have two record types so for both respective page layouts I added "Post" action. I need to enable this to support users - i.e. for Support Analyst, Support Manager and VP of Support profiles. In lightning record page, I have added the chatter component. for published and archived articles its working. Only for draft articles, post action is visible not the feed and it below it says "Chatter isn't enabled or the user doesn't have Chatter access.". For one draft article I can see both and for one I can see feed but no post. I am totally confused here. please help me out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
[image]
added chatter feed and post separately to test where it has issue

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled profile-based access for Chatter in your organization, and is the user's profile enabled for Chatter?  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_pbr_profiles.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes these are standard profiles. so its enabled automatically